# classOf[] for a higher-kinded type

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

Given `class Foo[F[_]]`, how do I get the `Class` object? The usual syntax doesn't work:

```
scala> classOf[Foo[_]]
<console>:9: error: _$1 takes no type parameters, expected: one
              classOf[Foo[_]]
                          ^
```

Neither does

```
scala> classOf[Foo[_[_]]]
<console>:9: error: _$1 does not take type parameters
              classOf[Foo[_[_]]]
                          ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, right. Leaving this in case someone looks for it:

```
scala> classOf[Foo[F] forSome { type F[_] }]
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res0: Class[Foo[_[_] <: Any]] = class Foo
```

Comment: This is a nice example of how you can get into trouble because Scala uses the same syntax `F[_]` to sometimes mean a higher-kinded type, sometimes an existential type.